# Writing a specific function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am stuck trying to figure out an exercise question.

"Write a function that, given a list of pairs (,b) returns the first a that is greater than its corresponding b".

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you've written that's not working? Show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function may help you:
You can find out more about iterating pairs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496657/how-can-i-access-each-element-of-a-pair-in-a-pair-list).

```
def f(pairs):
    for x, y in pairs:
        if x > y:
            return x
```