# How would I unpack a flat list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please understand, I searched for this and it already has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36993392/225020). However I'm looking for a different way to get this result. This could potentially be flagged as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993313/for-loop-with-multiple-iterating-values) although I think there is a cleaner answer for this possibly using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) *(most likely `groupby`)*.

Say I have a list `data`. And I want 3 values at a time assume the list is number of valuesⁿ long as to rule out improper amount of values at the end.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...]
```

Here's how I'd like to iterate through the list *(this code wouldn't work obviously)*:

```
for a, b, c in data:
    #perform operations
    pass
```

Now with the code above I'd like `a, b, c` to be `1, 2, 3` then `4, 5, 6` respectively in each iteration.
I'm sure there's a cleaner approach out there than the one in the answer I linked to.

For the lazy people that don't want to click on a link to see the approach I'm referring to, here it is:

> You can use slices if you want to iterate through a list by pairs of successive elements:
>
> ```
> >>>myList = [4, 5, 7, 23, 45, 65, 3445, 234]
> >>>for x,y in (myList[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(myList),2)):
> print(x,y)
>
> 4 5
> 7 23
> 45 65
> 3445 234
> ```

Comment: dang marked as duplicate anyway. Didn't find that one. Although I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/225020) answer the one I was trying to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a hacky solution with `iter` and `zip`:

```
i =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = iter(i)

for a, b, c in zip(*[d]*3):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Additionally if you want it to iterate over everything when your original list isn't divisible by three you can use `zip_longest` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


i =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
d = iter(i)

for a, b, c in zip_longest(*[d]*3):
  print(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 None None
```

Comment: I like this thanks! Now I want to see something along the lines of performance differences between this and something like @jspcal's approach

Comment: That's cool, having 3 copy of the same reference to the iterator in a list

Comment: Note this solution is precisely the [`itertools` `grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the docs, also available in 3rd party [`more_itertools.grouper`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.grouper).

Comment: @Jaba jspcal's approach should be faster since I'm building a list, unpacking, and passing things into zip. However iterating over a list is already really fast, and my assumption is that your performance bottleneck will be what you will do with a, b, and c instead of just the iteration.

Comment: While that's very true, I'm iterating over hundreds of millions of values in what I'm doing and will probably stick with what I have which is like @jspcal's approach I was only asking as it was peaking my interest due to another question I had seen earlier

Comment: @Jaba I did some timing here: https://repl.it/repls/UsefulSuperficialWorkers, for some reason my solution appears to be much faster. I think this is because it doesn't have to bind the values to variables during each cycle of the loop

Comment: @Primusa I cannot load up repl.it at my station but I tried running [this](https://pastebin.com/LqNhpY8T) code using a simple `d=a+b+c` and your approach is giving a `TypeError` on the line `for a in d:` Saying that int isnt iterable? I added the addition because maybe it just wasn’t looking at all the code dude to the pass?

Comment: I’m dumb.... I reassign `d` right above it... change `d=a+b+c` to `v=a+b+c`

Comment: @Jaba the variant above is the fastest out of the three. Times are (3.5, 7, and 9.18 seconds). Note that you have a bug in your code where you use an already used up iterable to test the second variant. The times I got were after I fixed this bug.

Comment: The replit link from above (https://repl.it/repls/UsefulSuperficialWorkers) has been updated to demonstrate the timings in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, yes it is! I ran it myself as well. It’s crazy that’s the fastest too I’m kinda taken back that it is.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use an iterator and increment the iterator when you want the next element in the chunk:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
it = iter(data)

for x in it:
    a = x
    b = next(it)
    c = next(it)
    print(a, b, c)
    # Do something with a, b, and c
```

Comment: Thank you, I do know this is a more traditional approach. unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for, I'd like to unpack it within the for declaration.