# Picking values from the list - how to make it more efficient

Tags: python

I'm trying to pick 8 values from the list and assign them to variables. How to simplify it, make it more efficient.

I was not enough specific. I would like to pick 8  values from the beginning of the list, make operation, add it to result, then pick next 8 number from the list and so on until the end of the list

```
input_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
index=0
for n in range(int(len(input_data)/8)):
        v1=input_data[n+index]
        x1=input_data[n+1+index] 
        y1=input_data[n+2+index]
        z1=input_data[n+3+index]
        v2=input_data[n+4+index]
        x2=input_data[n+5+index] 
        y2=input_data[n+6+index]
        z2=input_data[n+7+index]
        index+=7
        print(v1,x1,y1,z1,v2,x2,y2,z2)
```

Comment: so assigning the last 8 elements of list to the variables?

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: If you're only printing them, you can just slice the list.

Comment: I guess one optimization here off the bat is to use `range(1, 25)` instead of that list

Comment: As others have  hinted, it is not at all clear just what you are trying to accomplish, so we are not sure what to change. What is your end goal here? (Which 8 values do you really want, what could the input data be, etc.)

Comment: If it is just for printing, you can use        
  
  for n in range(0, len(input_data),6): print(input_data[n:n+7])

Comment: Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707972/225020), as I also had a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374598/how-would-i-unpack-a-flat-list) which relates very closely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) ... Also [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot optimise variable assignment in terms of speed, but you can in terms of readability:

```
input_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
for n in range(len(input_data)//8):
    v1, x1, y1, z1, v2, x2, y2, z2 = input_data[n*8:(n+1)*8]
```

Comment: I was looking exactly this, it looks better, it's shorter. I need only to catch what is happening inside the square bracket

Comment: Note the use of `//`. Integer division, this will not round up, which means if you have seven elements, it won't enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to only print it, you can do it using `slicing`:

```
start_index = -8
print(input_data[start_index:])
```

OR

If you want to assign them, you can use a `list` to store the values that can later be extracted separably.

```
vars_list = []
for i in range(start_index, 0):
    vars_list.append(input_data[i])


print(vars_list[0])
print(vars_list[1])
print(vars_list[2])
print(vars_list[3])
print(vars_list[4])
print(vars_list[5])
print(vars_list[6])
print(vars_list[7])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

EDIT:

Easier, one-liner killer:

```
start_index = -8
for i in range(len(input_data)//8): v1, x1, y1, z1, v2, x2, y2, z2 = input_data[start_index:]

print(v1, x1, y1, z1, v2, x2, y2, z2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fixed length of `input_data`:

```
for i in range(3):
    v1,x1,y1,z1,v2,x2,y2,z2 = input_data[i*8:(i+1)*8]
    print(v1,x1,y1,z1,v2,x2,y2,z2)
```

Or indefinite length (but multiple of 8) of `input_data`:

```
for i in range(0,len(input_data), 8):
    v1,x1,y1,z1,v2,x2,y2,z2 = input_data[i:i+8]
    print(v1,x1,y1,z1,v2,x2,y2,z2)
```

Which all prints same as OP's one

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Answer (score 0):

in python we can do this by

```
input_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
temp=input_data
randomly_picked=[]

for i in range(len(input_data)):
    v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8 = input_data[i:i+8]
```

Answer (score 0):

This improves on readability some:

```
input_data = range(1,25)
data = iter(input_data)
for v1, x1, y1, z1, v2, x2, y2, z2 in zip(*[data]*8):
     print(v1, x1, y1, z1, v2, x2, y2, z2)
```

prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374598/how-would-i-unpack-a-flat-list) which was answered with very similar intentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from random import sample 
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24] 
values = sample(list, 8) 
for x in values:     
    print(x)
```

This will select randomly eight numbers from your list and the for loop will print them.

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP wants. I thought the same though when I first read it.