# How to number a 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have these lists inside a list that I am trying to number. I also have two variables, row and column, which are taken as input.

```
lst = row*[column*[0]]
```

This makes lists inside a list that are filled with zeros, so if row = 6 and column = 10, it would look like:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How can I change it so it looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],   
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],     
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],    
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],     
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],     
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]]
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be the most "pythonic" way:

```
from pprint import pprint

rows = 6
cols = 10

lst = [[(j*cols+i) for i in range(1,cols+1)] for j in range(rows)]

pprint(lst)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]]
```

Comment: More pythonic than the ones without a nested nested for loop?

Comment: @fountainhead: Yes—while arguably not as "intuitive" as yours, it's still very efficient and readable.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be:

```
lst = []
for r in range(row):
    lst.append([])
    for c in range(column):
        lst[r].append(c + r * column)
```

This can be implemented more cleanly using numpy and reshaping like:

```
lst = numpy.arange(row * column).reshape(row, column).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 6):
    row = []
    for j in range(1,11):
        row.append(i*10+j)
    l.append(row)
l
>>>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
   [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
   [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
   [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
   [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using list comprehension as follows:

```
lst = [[(i+j*column)+1 for i in range(column)] for j in range(row)]
```

Comment: You've got your rows and columns backwards, see martineau's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using `zip` and `range`.

```
list(zip(*[iter(range(1, row*column+1))]*column))
```

This results in a list of tuples but if you need a list of lists, just `map` `list` to `zip`

```
list(map(list, zip(*[iter(range(1, row*column+1))]*column)))
```

Results:

`[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49], [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]`

Comment: Quite a bizarre approach, but fun nonetheless.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374626/225020) answer to one of my own questions is sooo useful and can be modified quite beautifully sometimes. That's all I did here

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Not only is it a fun/bizzare approach but it's about 5x faster than the list comp alternative. See https://repl.it/repls/GracefulThirdOpensource

Comment: That comparison is wrong, each produces completely different output (the corrected list comp is still slower, though)

Comment: I just realized that, why is your answer not producing OP's desired results oops not your answer

Comment: I didn't provide an answer.

Comment: I fixed the repl. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm not saying mine is better I'm just always looking at efficiency I guess

Answer (score 0):

The way I would consider approaching this is recognizing that you are generating a list of lists, as opposed to a 2D array.

Also, given your apparent level of experience I think a procedural approach might be a good start for you.

```
# Your given information
row = 6
col = 10

# Initialize an empty list of lists
lst = []

# Continuously append lists by converting range() objects
i = 1
while i <= (row * col):
  next_i = i + col
  arr.append(list(range(i, next_i)))
  i = i + next_i
```

Some good next steps would be to investigate the documentation for [range()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) and [list()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-list). At first glance they look like functions but they are actually an immutable and a mutable (respectively) [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

Note: A comment on your question says

> You happen to have created a list with a bunch of references *to the same inner list*.

To illustrate this, observe what happens in the python interactive interpreter when I try to modify (mutate) one element of the list of lists:

```
>>> row = 6
>>> column = 10
>>> lst = row*[column*[0]]
>>> lst
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> lst[0][0] = 999 # set just row 0, column 0 to 999
>>> lst
[[999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The result is that the first column of *every* row has been changed to 999. This is because when you "multiplied" the `list` created by `[column*[0]]` by `row`, what actually happened is you got `row` instances of the same `list`. So when you refer to one of them, you refer to all of them, in this way. Be careful with this kind of "list multiplication".

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
lst = [list(range(1+i*column, 1+(i+1)*column)) for i in range(row)]
```

**Output:**

```
print (lst)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]]
```

**Explanation:**

1. We're building an outer list, in which each element is an (inner) list of `int`.
2. The list comprehension builds the outer list.
3. The expression before the `for` loop, which is `list(range(1+i*column, 1+(i+1)*column))`, represents each element of this outer list. This element, which is a list of `int`, is first constructed as a range object using `range(1+i*column, 1+(i+1)*column)`. The range object returned by this is then passed to `list()` to convert it into a list.

Notice that the expression `range(1+i*column, 1+(i+1)*column)` is **intuitive**, because, it mirrors the fact that in the `i` th row, the values will "range" from `(1+i*column) to 1+(i+1)*column`. For example, in the 6x10 case, when `i` = 2, the values of the corresponding row will "range" from `1+2*10` to `1+(2+1)*10`.