# Unable to sync two "for loops" in python

Tags: python, for-loop, synchronization

I have two lists, the first list is hostnames to ssh to, the second list is a tunnel to look for on the given hostname.  I need the first item in list hostnames to run only the first item in list tunnels.  Then I need the second item in list hostnames to run only the second item in list tunnels. Below is a sample of what I was using, but clearly isn't working for me.

```
hostnames = ["router1", "router2"]
tunnels = ["Tu1000", "Tu5000"
for i in range (0, len(hostnames)):
 try:

        ssh1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh1.connect(hostnames[i], port=22, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        print "SSH connection to %s established.\n" % hostnames[i].upper()
        ssh = ssh1.invoke_shell()
        for j in range(0, len(tunnels)):

            ssh.send("!\n")
            ssh.send("en\n")
            ssh.send(password)
            ssh.send("\n!\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            output = ssh.recv(65535)

            ssh.send("sh int desc | i " + tunnels[j] + "\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            output = ssh.recv(65535)
            output = output.split(" ")
            cli_hostname = output[55]
```

Comment: When you ask a mechanic for help to diagnose a problem with your car hopefully you don't just point at your car and say "it doesn't work".

Comment: By the way, `for host in hostnames` looks cleaner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this -

```
hostnames = ["router1", "router2"]
tunnels = ["Tu1000", "Tu5000"]
for hostname, tunnel in zip(hostnames, tunnels):
  # Do stuff with `hostname` and `tunnel`
  ....
```

Read about `zip` function [here](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/zip.html).

Read about tuple unpacking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops).

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question, I wasn't able to find this hence my submission.  I'm going to look into this but it appears to help a lot. This is better than the below answer because I believe I can use hostname at one point through the loop and the tunnel at a different point in the same loop instance.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> for i in zip(hostnames, tunnels):
...   print i
...
('router1', 'Tu1000')
('router2', 'Tu5000')
```

Comment: You just copied my answer.

Comment: @Yasser this one was submitted first. Both are copies of the concept in the duplicate question in the comments

Comment: Mine was submitted first @cricket_007 "13:29:24Z". This one was submitted at "13:30:13Z". But its cool. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the router with its route directly as a tuple

```
data = [("router1", "Tu1000"),  ("router2", "Tu5000")]

for host, tunnel in data:
    # ssh to host 
    # send command to tunnel
```