# Environment: Python(3.6.4), how come the value(level) is different?

Tags: python

Hard to describe it, ref below codes, pls

For the var item1, I wonder:

Section1, item1's value is an element of lst, a tuple.
but from Section2, items1's value goes to next level, is an element of an element of lst.

### how to understand this?

```
 import random

 lst1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]
 lst2 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]
 lst = list(zip(lst1, lst2))

 print(lst)

 # section 1
 for item1 in lst:
     print(item1)

 # section 2
 for item1, item2 in lst:
     print(item1, item2)
```

---

output example:

```
[(34, 85), (9, 18), (56, 89), (69, 82), (21, 69), (21, 46), (39, 78), (19, 27), (33, 71), (94, 2)]
```

section1:

```
(34, 85)
...
(94, 2)
```

section2:

```
34 85
...
94 2
```

---

how come from section1 item1 = (34, 85) but item1 just = 34 from section2

Comment: We're going to need to see some code, your expectations, your actual results, and your thoughts and failed attempts on addressing the situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops is very relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst` is a list of tuple

```
[(34, 85), (9, 18)]
```

`for item1 in lst:` `item1` is a tuple `(34, 85)`

`for item1, item2 in lst:` `item1` is first element of the tuple `(item, item2)`, e.g `(34, 85)`

`tuple` in python is flexible, I will expand a bit.

empty tuple: `a = ()`

1 item tuple: `a = (1,)` or `b = 1,` or `c = [],` but not `a = (1)`

for our cases here 2 items tuple:

`(34, 85)` is the same as `34, 85`

`(item1, item2)` is same as `item1, item2`

Comment: thanks, I know, but...how come the item1 changed from tuple to an element of the tuple automatically? after just add an item2 follow it!

Comment: My point is, from "for item1 in lst:" the item1 point to a tuple, but just add a item2 after item1, likes "for item1, item2 in lst:", then the item1 point to a element of the tuple!

Comment: I want to know the mechanism, of item1 point to where of the lst.