# How does updating a Python for loop within a list work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

In Michael Nielsen's tutorial on neural networks he has the following code:

```
def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    """The ``mini_batch`` is a list of tuples ``(x, y)``, and ``eta``
    is the learning rate."""
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
    self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]
```

I understand what tuples and lists are and I understand what the zip function is doing but I don't understand how the variables nb, dnb, nw, and dnw are updated on these 2 lines of code:

```
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
```

Can anyone help explain the magic going on in these 2 lines?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: a) you mean a chapter from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com? Which? b) `np` is `numpy`?

Comment: Are you (a) not understanding how `for` can appear inside a list: `[x for y in z]`, or (b) how two names can be assigned simultaneously: `for a, b in x`?

Comment: I would like clarification on `nb+dnb for nb` and `dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)` separately to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tuple unpacking in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines are typical examples of Python [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

In essence, for your first list:

```
nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
```

this means:

1. Take the 1st pair from `zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)`; name them `nb` and `dnb`
2. add them (`nb+dnb`)
3. make the result the 1st element of new list `nabla_b`
4. Go to step one for the 2nd pair etc appending the results to `nabla_b`, until all pairs from `zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)` have been exhausted

As a simple example, the list comprehension below:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
print(squares)
# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

is equivalent with the following `for` loop:

```
squares = []

for x in range(10):
    squares.append(x**2)

print(squares)
# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

See [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) for more examples and a quick introduction.

Comment: Ahhh, I got it now. Thank you. My confusion was treating `nb+dnb for nb` and `dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)` as separate statements that would somehow return a list of 2 elements into nabla_b. This is not correct at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` function sticks the two lists together element by element, so that if you gave it:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

`zip(a, b)` would return:

```
[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), ...]
```

(each element being a `tuple`)

You can unpack elements of `list`s that are `tuple`s (or `list`s) using the a comma between each variable in the element `tuple`:

```
for elem_a, elem_b in zip(a, b):
    print(elem_a, elem_b)
```

This would print:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

So in your case, it's adding the two lists `nabla_b` and `delta_nabla_b` elementwise, so you get one list with each element being the sum of the corresponding elements in the zipped lists.

It might look a bit strange because the `for` loop is all on one line, but this is called a "list comprehension". Simple list comprehensions read like English.

Comment: You just overlooked the comprehension part, which I believe is part of OP's misunderstanding. +1 though, although you simplified (maybe not on purpose) the behaviour of `zip`. It only returns a list in Python 2, while it returns a `zip` object (ie a generator) in Python 3 - still, I find it much more reasonable to present it as you did to a newcomer.

Comment: @Rightleg I concur - I chose to focus on the list comprehension part myself since OP made explicit that "I understand what the zip function is doing"...

Comment: Yes I always miss the crux of the question and go off on tangents. I only outlined explicitly what zip was doing because that was necessary to explain the unpacking in my view.