# Getting Detailed Information About Folders And Their Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to `os.walk()` through 5 folders containing mp3 files. I want to display the timestamps of each folder and file as well as their sizes and of course names.

With

```
for x in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
   print(x)
```

I am able to get the folder and filenames, but don't know how to iterate through them as each
folder is one tuple. I want to assign each tuple to a different variable to access them better, but I don't know how to do that while in a for loop.

Any ideas how to do that? Or how to accomplish what I'm trying to do in a better way? Thanks!

Comment: use file full path as key in dictionary and in values you can save the properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are tuples unpacked in for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867882/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `for` loops to access the individual files:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk( os.getcwd() ):
    for filename in filenames:
        # your code here
        # be aware that 'filename' is not the relative path to the file
        # you can get that by concatenating 'dirpath' and 'filename' together
```

`dirpath` refers to the current path in the walk

`dirnames` is a list of the directories in `dirpath`

`filenames` is a list of the files in `dirpath`

Comment: That solved it! Thanks brother!