# How is a list element being converted to a Tuple

Tags: python, for-loop

I am learning python. My research using google hasn't hit on any description on what is occurring here. I'm doing some basic exercises.

A person on a the codewars website put this solution down for a problem:

```
data=[[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]]

def openOrSenior(data):
  return ["Senior" if age >= 55 and handicap >= 8 else "Open" for (age, handicap) in data]
```

I'm unable to understand how they can use a tuple to access the sublist elements. What is this called in Python and how does it work?

```
for (age, handicap) in data
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/how-are-tuples-unpacked-in-for-loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are tuples unpacked in for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/how-are-tuples-unpacked-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a tuple, that's just sequence unpacking.

`(x, y) = [1, 2]` for example is perfectly legal since the left-hand side just means "assign the first element to `x`, and the second element to `y`". It's not a tuple whose type matches the type of the object being unpacked.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this. Lot's to learn.

Comment: @Dan You're welcome. And yes there is.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is known as "tuple unpacking". In simple terms, it's a concise manner to extract items from a list and assign variables to these values.

In this specific case, the `for (age, handicap)` in data is iterating through the data list, and for each sublist within data, it's extracting the first element as `age` and the second element as `handicap`. It's assuming that each sublist contains two elements, and it unpacks them into the variables `age` and `handicap` respectively.

So, for instance, with `data=[[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12]]`, during the iteration, the first iteration would assign `age = 18` and `handicap = 20`, the second would assign `age = 45` and `handicap = 2`, and so on until it exhausts the sublists in data.

In my opinion, Tuple Unpacking is a very powerful and efficient way to handle iterating through sequences.

Answer (score 0):

that is not tuple it just unpacks the sublist if you use without parenthesis
it still will work like below

```
data=[[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]]

def openOrSenior(data):
  return ["Senior" if age >= 55 and handicap >= 8 else "Open" for age, handicap in data]
```